# How to decode the dollar sign from url using javascript to populate the input field?

Tags: jquery

Please let me know in comments if Im not explaining good.

As the question title says everything can you please tell me how can I decode the dollar sign($) as it goes to %24 in url when submited from the page like you can use this link for example.

http://mubisoft.fh2web.com/Kayak/submit.html

try submiting data and it will get the data from url and will try to populate the input field again but when it tries to get data from url it take %24 with it instead of $ sign.

here is the code of javascript that im using in it.

```
var url = window.location.href;
    var input = $( "#one" );
    var input2 = $( "#two" );
    if(url.indexOf("?") >= 0){
var params = url.split('?');
var params1 = params[1].split('&');
var a  = params1[0].split('=');
var r = a[1];
var a  = params1[1].split('=');
    input2.val(a[1]);
    input.val(r); // here are populating data getting from url
}
    $( "#one" ).blur(function() {
        if(input.val().substring(0,1) == '$'){
            return false;
        }else{
            input.val( "$ "+input.val() )
        }
    });
```

Comment: Decode it properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Try encodeURI() funtion

Comment: @Blender thanks let me check this..

Comment: @phpmashcode can you please paste the code..

Comment: @blender Can you please check the code on link I added this function on it but it is returning empty.

Comment: @phpmashcode I tried encodeURI() but not working.

Comment: @user3310343 I think you want decodeURI() since you want to decode `%24` to the `$` character - or maybe i'm misunderstanding the problem

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ I tried this but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your encoded string through this function:

```
decodeURIComponent( encodedString );
```

Full code for getting variables out of the querystring and decoding:

```
//this code executes immediately and pulls all the variables
var QueryString = function () {
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    pair[1] = decodeURIComponent( pair[1] ); //encoded characters are decoded here
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }
  } 
    return query_string;
} ();

//then you can access the querystring variables like this
QueryString.varName
```

Comment: Thanks man decodeURIComponent() worked but it is not removing + sign from it.

Comment: Try adding `query = query.replace("+"," ");` before the `var vars...` line.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `decodeURI` doesn't decode the dollar sign (`$`), you should use a `.replace()`:

```
var myURL = 'www.somesite.com/somepage.php?price=%2420';

myURL = myURL.replace(/%24/g,'$'); // www.somesite.com/somepage.php?price=$20
```

Comment: Alternately, `encodeURIComponent()` does encode the dollar sign ($) as "%24" so you could use `decodeURIComponent()` to unencode it